# How to upgrade from php 5.2.14 to php 5.3.3 on SLES11

Tags: php, upgrade, sles11

I am in the process of installing dokuwiki on my SLES11 server, but for some reason, dokuwiki only wants php 5.3.3 and up. I realized that after installing php through the system, and it installed 5.2.14.

I now want to either upgrade to the newest version, or contemplating removing the older version and installing the newer one. I want the easier method, on some guidance on how to go about the easier method.

Please let me know if any clarification is needed.

Thanks in advance for you're responses

Answer (score 0):

I would check and see what the latest version is available though the SLES repos, if there is a 5.3.3 version, then a simple zypper up will do the necessary clean update. I would avoid using an external source for the install as the whole premiss of SLES is certified updates for enterprise level updates, especially on production systems.

To try and remove the earlier version first would probably cause more issues on dependancies for other packages you may have installed.